# content_for in Ruby on Rails with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, partial-views, content-for

I have a problem with the content_for in RoR, I have a remote call to the controller
it contains the javascript update.js.erb render a partial _update.html.erb and within the partial content_for where there is the inside of it there is a javascript that needs to be added to the Head of the html page

controller

```
def uploadimage
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end
```

update.js.erb

```
$('#reloadimage').html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'users/crop' )%>");
```

partial _crop.html.erb

```
<% content_for(:head1) do %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Jcrop.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
  $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    onChange: update_crop,
    onSelect: update_crop,
    setSelect: [0, 0, 500, 500],
    aspectRatio: 1
  });
});
</script>

<% end %>
```

layaout application.html.erb

```
<head>
....

<%= yield :head1 %>

....
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. Remember you are manipulating HTML on the client side, the layout is already rendered.

Add your changes to the head in the `update.js.erb`:

```
$("head").append(.....);
```